# How to do use .count() in function and lambda

Tags: python, function, count

I am a beginner of python, thank you so much!

function:

```
def count(c):
    return c.count(1)

count(1,1,1,11,1,12,1)
```

This function doesn't work, I want to create a function count how many `1`’s?

lambda:

```
counts = lambda m:count('m') 
counts('what is you name, my name is mammy!')
```

This lambda doesn't work, too. I want to create a lambda count how many `'m'`'s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `*` in front of `c` to make it take all the leftover arguments and sets it to a `list`

```
def count(*c):
    return c.count(1)

count(1,1,1,11,1,12,1)
```

and the `lambda` function can be:

```
counts = lambda m: m.count('m') 
counts('what is you name, my name is mammy!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example fails because you're passing multiple arguments, and it only accepts one (presumably a `list`). One way to fix it would be to pass a `list`:

```
def count(c):
    return c.count(1)

print(count([1,1,1,11,1,12,1]))  # 5
```

Another way to fix it is to allow multiple parameters but *treat* them as a `list`. Here's how you can do that:

```
def count(*c):
    return c.count(1)

print(count(1,1,1,11,1,12,1))  # 5
```

Your second example is missing a thing to call `count` on. Again, one possible fix:

```
counts = lambda x: x.count('m')
print(counts('what is you name, my name is mammy!'))  # 6
```

Comment: Thank you so much!